# Create multiple pdf from a multipage single pdf

Tags: pdf, export

Have a large multipage .pdf, and would like to export all pages as single pdf?
Help with the script required, using pdftk??
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `pdftk in.pdf burst`. The equivalent in cpdf is `cpdf -split in.pdf -o %%%.pdf` or similar.